# How to get response SSL certificate from requests in python?

Tags: python, http, https, request, python-requests

Trying to get the SSL certificate from a response in [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: If you don't mind making a new request, you could just use get_server_certificate() from the ssl module. import ssl; ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.apple.com', 443))

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`requests` deliberately wraps up low-level stuff like this. Normally, the only thing you want to do is to [verify that the certs are valid](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification). To do that, just pass `verify=True`. If you want to use a non-standard cacert bundle, you can pass that too. For example:

```
resp = requests.get('https://example.com', verify=True, cert=['/path/to/my/ca.crt'])
```

Also, `requests` is primarily a set of wrappers around other libraries, mostly [`urllib3`](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) and the stdlib's [`http.client`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) (or, for 2.x, `httplib`) and [`ssl`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).

Sometimes, the answer is just to get at the lower-level objects (e.g., `resp.raw` is the `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`), but in many cases that's impossible.

And this is one of those cases. The only objects that ever see the certs are an `http.client.HTTPSConnection` (or a `urllib3.connectionpool.VerifiedHTTPSConnection`, but that's just a subclass of the former) and an `ssl.SSLSocket`, and neither of those exist anymore by the time the request returns. (As the name `connectionpool` implies, the `HTTPSConnection` object is stored in a pool, and may be reused as soon as it's done; the `SSLSocket` is a member of the `HTTPSConnection`.)

So, you need to patch things so you can copy the data up the chain. It may be as simple as this:

```
HTTPResponse = requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse
orig_HTTPResponse__init__ = HTTPResponse.__init__
def new_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    orig_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        self.peercert = self._connection.sock.getpeercert()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_HTTPResponse__init__

HTTPAdapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response = HTTPAdapter.build_response
def new_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp):
    response = orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp)
    try:
        response.peercert = resp.peercert
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return response
HTTPAdapter.build_response = new_HTTPAdapter_build_response
```

That's untested, so no guarantees; you may need to patch more than that.

Also, subclassing and overriding would probably be cleaner than monkeypatching (especially since `HTTPAdapter` was designed to be subclassed).

Or, even better, forking `urllib3` and `requests`, modifying your fork, and (if you think this is legitimately useful) submitting pull requests upstream.

Anyway, now, from your code, you can do this:

```
resp.peercert
```

This will give you a dict with `'subject'` and `'subjectAltName'` keys, as returned by `pyopenssl.WrappedSocket.getpeercert`. If you instead want more information about the cert, try [Christophe Vandeplas's variant of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072170/1709587) that lets you get an `OpenSSL.crypto.X509` object. If you want to get the entire peer certificate chain, see [GoldenStake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47931103/1709587).

Of course you may also want to pass along all the information necessary to verify the cert, but that's even easier, because it already passes through the top level.

Comment: Wow, this is very complete.  Thanks a lot!  I'll work on it and see how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Unfortunately, when the server uses `Connection: close` and closes the connection immediately after the data is transferred, I still would not get the "peercert". I had to patch `requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection.connect` too to first call the original function and then immediately get the `self.sock.getpeercert()` and then pass it up the chain.

Comment: Modern requests breaks this patch as of 2.24.0 for systems that have ssl available: https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/5443/files

Answer (score 13):

To start, [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904808/2197939) is very complete. While chasing the proposed `connection-close` issue of [Kalkran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5384754/kalkran) I actually discovered that the `peercert` didn't contain detailed information about the SSL Certificate.

I dug deeper in the connection and socket info and extracted the `self.sock.connection.get_peer_certificate()` function which contains great functions like:

- `get_subject()` for CN
- `get_notAfter()` and `get_notBefore()` for expiration dates
- `get_serial_number()` and `get_signature_algorithm()` for crypto related technical details
- ...

Note that these are only available if you have `pyopenssl` installed on your system. Under the hood, `urllib3` uses `pyopenssl` if it's available and the standard library's `ssl` module otherwise. The `self.sock.connection` attribute shown below only exists if `self.sock` is a `urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.WrappedSocket`, not if it's a `ssl.SSLSocket`. You can install `pyopenssl` with `pip install pyopenssl`.

Once that's done, the code becomes:

```
import requests

HTTPResponse = requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse
orig_HTTPResponse__init__ = HTTPResponse.__init__
def new_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    orig_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        self.peer_certificate = self._connection.peer_certificate
    except AttributeError:
        pass
HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_HTTPResponse__init__

HTTPAdapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response = HTTPAdapter.build_response
def new_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp):
    response = orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp)
    try:
        response.peer_certificate = resp.peer_certificate
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return response
HTTPAdapter.build_response = new_HTTPAdapter_build_response

HTTPSConnection = requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
orig_HTTPSConnection_connect = HTTPSConnection.connect
def new_HTTPSConnection_connect(self):
    orig_HTTPSConnection_connect(self)
    try:
        self.peer_certificate = self.sock.connection.get_peer_certificate()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
HTTPSConnection.connect = new_HTTPSConnection_connect
```

You will be able to access the result easily:

```
r = requests.get('https://yourdomain.tld', timeout=0.1)
print('Expires on: {}'.format(r.peer_certificate.get_notAfter()))
print(dir(r.peer_certificate))
```

If, like me, you want to ignore SSL Certificate warnings just add the following in the top of the file and do not SSL verify:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

r = requests.get('https://yourdomain.tld', timeout=0.1, verify=False)
print(dir(r.peer_certificate))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the great addition to the answer! +1.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for everyone's awesome answers.

It helped me over engineer an answer to this question:

[How to add a custom CA Root certificate to the CA Store used by Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-python-in-window/52961564#52961564)

## UPDATE 2019-02-12

> Please take a look at [Cert Human: SSL Certificates for Humans](https://github.com/lifehackjim/cert_human) for an impressive rewrite of my https://github.com/neozenith/get-ca-py project by [lifehackjim](https://github.com/lifehackjim).
>
> I have archived the original repository now.

## Stand alone snippet

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Get Certificates from a request and dump them.
"""

import argparse
import sys

import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

"""
Inspired by the answers from this Stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903528/how-to-get-response-ssl-certificate-from-requests-in-python

What follows is a series of patching the low level libraries in requests.
"""

"""
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47931103/622276
"""

sock_requests = requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.WrappedSocket


def new_getpeercertchain(self, *args, **kwargs):
    x509 = self.connection.get_peer_cert_chain()
    return x509


sock_requests.getpeercertchain = new_getpeercertchain

"""
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904808/622276
"""

HTTPResponse = requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse
orig_HTTPResponse__init__ = HTTPResponse.__init__


def new_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    orig_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        self.peercertchain = self._connection.sock.getpeercertchain()
    except AttributeError:
        pass


HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_HTTPResponse__init__

HTTPAdapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response = HTTPAdapter.build_response


def new_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp):
    response = orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp)
    try:
        response.peercertchain = resp.peercertchain
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return response


HTTPAdapter.build_response = new_HTTPAdapter_build_response

"""
Attempt to wrap in a somewhat usable CLI
"""


def cli(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Request any URL and dump the certificate chain")
    parser.add_argument("url", metavar="URL", type=str, nargs=1, help="Valid https URL to be handled by requests")

    verify_parser = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
    verify_parser.add_argument("--verify", dest="verify", action="store_true", help="Explicitly set SSL verification")
    verify_parser.add_argument(
        "--no-verify", dest="verify", action="store_false", help="Explicitly disable SSL verification"
    )
    parser.set_defaults(verify=True)

    return vars(parser.parse_args(args))


def dump_pem(cert, outfile="ca-chain.crt"):
    """Use the CN to dump certificate to PEM format"""
    PyOpenSSL = requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
    pem_data = PyOpenSSL.OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(PyOpenSSL.OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
    issuer = cert.get_issuer().get_components()

    print(pem_data.decode("utf-8"))

    with open(outfile, "a") as output:
        for part in issuer:
            output.write(part[0].decode("utf-8"))
            output.write("=")
            output.write(part[1].decode("utf-8"))
            output.write(",\t")
        output.write("\n")
        output.write(pem_data.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli_args = cli(sys.argv[1:])

    url = cli_args["url"][0]
    req = requests.get(url, verify=cli_args["verify"])
    for cert in req.peercertchain:
        dump_pem(cert)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests
import json
import ssl

with requests.get("https://www.google.com", stream=True) as response:
   certificate_info_raw = response.raw.connection.sock.getpeercert(True)
   pem_cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(certificate_info_raw)
   print(pem_cert)
   certificate_info = response.raw.connection.sock.getpeercert()
   print(json.dumps(certificate_info, indent=4))
```

The Output is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

{
    "subject": [
        [
            [
                "commonName",
                "www.google.com"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "issuer": [
        [
            [
                "countryName",
                "US"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "organizationName",
                "Google Trust Services LLC"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "commonName",
                "GTS CA 1C3"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "version": 3,
    "serialNumber": "029AA3D282DC117C0A1458D6EABCFF02",
    "notBefore": "Apr  3 08:25:07 2023 GMT",
    "notAfter": "Jun 26 08:25:06 2023 GMT",
    "subjectAltName": [
        [
            "DNS",
            "www.google.com"
        ]
    ],
    "OCSP": [
        "http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1c3"
    ],
    "caIssuers": [
        "http:/../Playground/"
    ],
    "crlDistributionPoints": [
        "http:/../Playground/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code.

Answer (score 3):

This, although not pretty at all, works:

```
import requests

req = requests.get('https://httpbin.org')
pool = req.connection.poolmanager.connection_from_url('https://httpbin.org')
conn = pool.pool.get()
# get() removes it from the pool, so put it back in
pool.pool.put(conn)
print(conn.sock.getpeercert())
```

Comment: This only works if the connection is still alive, which is not guaranteed. For example, if the other side sends a `Connection: close`. Or if you've sent out other requests (especially if you're using this in an async or threaded context). Or if `urllib3` just feels like it for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 3):

To start, [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904808/2197939) is very complete

But I would like to add, that in the case you're looking for the peer cert chain, you would need to patch yet another piece of code

```
import requests
sock_requests = requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.WrappedSocket
def new_getpeercertchain(self,*args, **kwargs):
    x509 = self.connection.get_peer_cert_chain()
    return x509
sock_requests.getpeercertchain = new_getpeercertchain
```

after that you can call it in a very similiar manner as the accepted answer

```
HTTPResponse = requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse
orig_HTTPResponse__init__ = HTTPResponse.__init__
def new_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    orig_HTTPResponse__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        self.peercertchain = self._connection.sock.getpeercertchain()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_HTTPResponse__init__

HTTPAdapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response = HTTPAdapter.build_response
def new_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp):
    response = orig_HTTPAdapter_build_response(self, request, resp)
    try:
        response.peercertchain = resp.peercertchain
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return response
HTTPAdapter.build_response = new_HTTPAdapter_build_response
```

you will get `resp.peercertchain` which contains a `tuple` of [`OpenSSL.crypto.X509`](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509-objects) objects

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```py
import requests

with requests.get("https://www.bilibili.com", stream=True) as response:
    certificate_info = response.raw.connection.sock.getpeercert()
    subject = dict(x[0] for x in certificate_info['subject'])
    issuer = dict(x[0] for x in certificate_info['issuer'])

    print("commonName:", subject['commonName'])
    print("issuer:", issuer['commonName'])
```

Then the output is :

```bash
commonName: *.bilibili.com
issuer: GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
```

Wish to help you.

Comment: Does not work for me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getpeercert'`. What am I missing?

Comment: could you show me the code?

Comment: Hm, I could verify that this works while providing the code snippet. I tested the snippet with self-signed certificates beforehand. May this be the reason I got the error?

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot from the above answers.

In order to solve the problem of connection: close, I have combined the answers of Mark Amenry and Yin Lei to come up with the following solution.

May it help.

```
# from Connection get SSL certificate patch
HTTPSConnection = requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
orig_HTTPSConnection_connect = HTTPSConnection.connect
def new_HTTPSConnection_connect(self):
    orig_HTTPSConnection_connect(self)
    try:
        self.peer_certificate = self.sock.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
    except AttributeError as e:
        pass
HTTPSConnection.connect = new_HTTPSConnection_connect
```

And then

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    certificate_info = r.raw.connection.peer_certificate
    print(certificate_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the details of a certificate such as CN and expiry date the following script adapted from this [example](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/OpenSSL.SSL/Connection/do_handshake/python-connection-do_handshake-method-examples.html#0xc81e542f9ae7026a00e4963ac8f4950c49bff4296318180592598f948092167d-13,,43,) works well. It also avoids some errors I got which I assume were due to incorrect/incompatible versions of requests and urllib3: "AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'connection'" and "AttributeError: 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'peer_certificate'"

```
from OpenSSL.SSL import Connection, Context, SSLv3_METHOD, TLSv1_2_METHOD
from datetime import datetime, time
import socket
host = 'www.google.com'
try:
    try:
        ssl_connection_setting = Context(SSLv3_METHOD)
    except ValueError:
        ssl_connection_setting = Context(TLSv1_2_METHOD)
    ssl_connection_setting.set_timeout(5)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, 443))
        c = Connection(ssl_connection_setting, s)
        c.set_tlsext_host_name(str.encode(host))
        c.set_connect_state()
        c.do_handshake()
        cert = c.get_peer_certificate()
        print("Is Expired: ", cert.has_expired())
        print("Issuer: ", cert.get_issuer())
        subject_list = cert.get_subject().get_components()
        cert_byte_arr_decoded = {}
        for item in subject_list:
            cert_byte_arr_decoded.update({item[0].decode('utf-8'): item[1].decode('utf-8')})
        print(cert_byte_arr_decoded)
        if len(cert_byte_arr_decoded) > 0:
            print("Subject: ", cert_byte_arr_decoded)
        if cert_byte_arr_decoded["CN"]:
            print("Common Name: ", cert_byte_arr_decoded["CN"])
        end_date = datetime.strptime(str(cert.get_notAfter().decode('utf-8')), "%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ")
        print("Not After (UTC Time): ", end_date)
        diff = end_date - datetime.now()
        print('Summary: "{}" SSL certificate expires on {} i.e. {} days.'.format(host, end_date, diff.days))
        c.shutdown()
        s.close()
except:
    print("Connection to {} failed.".format(host))
```

This script requires Python 3 and pyOpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner(-ish) solution, based on previous very good answers !

1. need to patch requests.Adapter source file before overriding
   HTTPResponse class (**pending pull request: https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/6039**):

   - add static class variable to **class HTTPAdapter(BaseAdapter)** : **_clsHTTPResponse = HTTPResponse**
   - modify **send()** method to use _clsHTTPResponse  rather than direct HTTPResponse object creation:   **resp = _clsHTTPResponse.from_httplib(...**
2. use this code:

```py
"""
Subclassing HTTP / requests to get peer_certificate back from lower levels
"""
from typing import Optional, Mapping, Any
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, DEFAULT_POOLBLOCK
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager,key_fn_by_scheme
from urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPSConnectionPool,HTTPConnectionPool
from urllib3.connection import HTTPSConnection,HTTPConnection
from urllib3.response import HTTPResponse as URLLIB3_HTTPResponse

#force urllib3 to use pyopenssl
import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()  

class HTTPSConnection_withcert(HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.peer_certificate = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
    def connect(self):
        res = super().connect() 
        self.peer_certificate = self.sock.connection.get_peer_certificate()
        return res

class HTTPResponse_withcert(URLLIB3_HTTPResponse):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.peer_certificate = None
        res = super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        self.peer_certificate = self._connection.peer_certificate
        return res
       
class HTTPSConnectionPool_withcert(HTTPSConnectionPool):
    ConnectionCls   = HTTPSConnection_withcert
    ResponseCls     = HTTPResponse_withcert
    
class PoolManager_withcert(PoolManager): 
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_pools: int = 10,
        headers: Optional[Mapping[str, str]] = None,
        **connection_pool_kw: Any,
    ) -> None:   
        super().__init__(num_pools,headers,**connection_pool_kw)
        self.pool_classes_by_scheme = {"http": HTTPConnectionPool, "https": HTTPSConnectionPool_withcert}
        self.key_fn_by_scheme = key_fn_by_scheme.copy()
                
class HTTPAdapter_withcert(HTTPAdapter):
    _clsHTTPResponse = HTTPResponse_withcert
    def build_response(self, request, resp):
        response = super().build_response( request, resp)
        response.peer_certificate = resp.peer_certificate
        return response

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=DEFAULT_POOLBLOCK, **pool_kwargs):
        #do not call super() to not initialize PoolManager twice
        # save these values for pickling
        self._pool_connections  = connections
        self._pool_maxsize      = maxsize
        self._pool_block        = block

        self.poolmanager        = PoolManager_withcert(num_pools=connections, 
                                                   maxsize=maxsize,
                                                   block=block, 
                                                   strict=True, 
                                                   **pool_kwargs)
class Session_withcert(Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter_withcert())
```

3. And thats all !
   You can now use your new session Session_withcert() like the base one, but you can also do :

```py
ss= Session_withcert()
resp=ss.get("https://www.google.fr")
resp.peer_certificate.get_subject()
print(resp.peer_certificate.get_subject())
```

which will output:

```
<X509Name object '/CN=*.google.fr'>
```