# Python Retrieve CA chain

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

What is the python way for getting complete ssl ca certificate chain from the server.
In other words, is Pythons(2.7) ssl_wrapper has any method that can do

```
openssl s_client **-showcerts** connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
```

I want to be able to achive showcerts from python side not using subproc

There is a way to do the same in Python 2.7.9+ with SSLContext but trying to achive this with Python < 2.7.9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting certificate chain with Python 3.3 SSL module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145097/getting-certificate-chain-with-python-3-3-ssl-module)

Comment: Steffen we want to achieve this with python < 2.7.9  Where the SSLContext is not available.

Comment: Maybe you should put such information into your question.