# Dump an invalid cert chain without OpenSSL?

Tags: python, ssl, pki

Is it possible to retrieve an **invalid** certificate chain (specifically, one which terminates in a never-before-seen root certificate) with just the Python 3.10 standard library?

I modified the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308901/1874170) incorporating the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122033/1874170), but I'm still getting an empty result to `.getpeercert()`.

```py
import socket
from contextlib import closing

from ssl import SSLContext  # Modern SSL?
from ssl import HAS_SNI  # Has SNI?
from ssl import PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT, CERT_NONE, CERT_REQUIRED

from pprint import pprint

def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, cert_reqs=None,
                    ca_certs=None, server_hostname=None, check_hostname=True,
                    ssl_version=None):

    context = SSLContext(ssl_version)
    context.check_hostname = check_hostname
    context.verify_mode = cert_reqs

    if ca_certs:
        try:
            context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
        # Py32 raises IOError
        # Py33 raises FileNotFoundError
        except Exception as e:  # Reraise as SSLError
            raise ssl.SSLError(e)

    if certfile:
        # FIXME: This block needs a test.
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)

    if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
        return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

    return context.wrap_socket(sock)

def __main__(hostname):
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
        s.connect((hostname, 443))

        sslSocket = ssl_wrap_socket(s,
                                    ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT, 
                                    cert_reqs=CERT_NONE,  # https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122033/1874170
                                    check_hostname=False,
                                    server_hostname=hostname)

        return sslSocket.getpeercert()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    pprint(__main__(*(sys.argv[1:] or ['python.neverssl.com'])))
```

What am I missing?

Is it *possible* for Python to retrieve this information without external native code such as OpenSSL?

If there are any 3rd-party libraries that are capable of retrieving this information and *don't* require native code, **how do they do it**?

Comment: get_peer_cert_chain from OpenSSL.SSL provides this. Not in the standard library but ssl itself does not provide this.

Comment: *“If that question doesn’t answer your issue, edit your question to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours.”* -- my question as-stated (inclusive of the title) has 6 English sentences, and **4 of them** highlight and re-emphasize the difference between that question and mine. If it's anything, it's not a "duplicate".

Comment: Have you actually read the [Python 3 `SSLSocket.getpeercert(binary_form=False)` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-sockets)?  It says things like "If the certificate was not validated, the dict is empty."  Given you're setting `ca_certs=None`, there's no way the certificate could have been validated - `getpeercert()` is a dead end without that validation.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL functionality in Python is implemented using OpenSSL in the [ssl library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html). The relevant function needed to get the originally send certificates is [SSL_get_peer_cert_chain](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_peer_cert_chain.html). It is not exposed from the ssl library though and not by any other part of the standard library either.

One can use [pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/) though which provides this functionality. See [Get or build PEM certificate chain in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039393/get-or-build-pem-certificate-chain-in-python) for how to use it.

> ... but I'm still getting an empty result to .getpeercert().

Note that it is possible with the standard library to get the server certificate even in case of an invalid certificate - see [Python getting common name from URL using ssl.getpeercert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478536/python-getting-common-name-from-url-using-ssl-getpeercert). But `getpeercert` will only provide the server certificate. It does not include the chain send by the server as explicitly asked for in the question.

Comment: Hmm. `pyOpenSSL` [requires `cryptography`](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/22.0.0/setup.py#L96), which requires extensive tooling to build but at least [provides prebuilt wheels for common operating systems](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/38.0.1/docs/installation.rst).