# Get or build PEM certificate chain in Python

Tags: python, ssl, pem

Is it possible to get the whole certificate chain in a PEM format using ssl with Python ? I can get the specific one with :

```
import ssl
addr = '192.0.2.1'
cert_str = ssl.get_server_certificate((addr, 443))
```

which give me something like :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But I'd like to have :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible since I can download this from my web browser. Any idea ?

(I have already checked [Getting certificate chain with Python 3.3 SSL module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145097/getting-certificate-chain-with-python-3-3-ssl-module) but I'm not sure this is what I want ...)

**EDIT:** What I tried after *Patrick Mevzek* answer :

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket
dst = ('192.0.2.1', 443)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_alpn_protos([b'http/1.1'])
if sock.connect_ex(dst) == 0:
    connection = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
    cert_str = connection.get_peer_cert_chain()
```

But cert_str is None. I think this is because i'm missing something with the use of OpenSSL.

Comment: "But cert_str is None." see remark in my updated answer. From observations, try to call it only **after** having exchanged some data in the TLS stream, because it is not populated correctly before that. And PS: please do not use `1.2.3.4` as placeholder in questions/documentation, see guidance in RFC5737 to obfuscate IP addresses, and so you can use `192.0.2.x`

Comment: Thanks for your answers and advices, I'll keep that in mind !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `OpenSSL` library in Python, you have `get_peer_cert_chain` that you can apply on your connection object, it will give you a list of certificates as sent by the server, so the end certificate with all intermediates one if needed.

See https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html#connection-objects :

> get_peer_cert_chain()
>
> Retrieve the other side’s certificate (if any)
>
> Returns:   A list of X509 instances giving the peer’s certificate chain, or None if it does not have one.

Here is one crude example (without any error handling):

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket

dst = ('www.google.com', 443)
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
s = socket.create_connection(dst)
s = SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
s.set_connect_state()
s.set_tlsext_host_name(dst[0])

s.sendall('HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n\n')
s.recv(16)

certs = s.get_peer_cert_chain()
for pos, cert in enumerate(certs):
   print "Certificate #" + str(pos)
   for component in cert.get_subject().get_components():
       print "Subject %s: %s" % (component)
   print "notBefore:" + cert.get_notBefore()
   print "notAfter:" + cert.get_notAfter()
   print "version:" + str(cert.get_version())
   print "sigAlg:" + cert.get_signature_algorithm()
   print "digest:" + cert.digest('sha256')
```

which gives:

```
Certificate #0
Subject C: US
Subject ST: California
Subject L: Mountain View
Subject O: Google LLC
Subject CN: www.google.com
notBefore:20180612133452Z
notAfter:20180821121300Z
version:2
sigAlg:sha256WithRSAEncryption
digest:06:C5:12:EB:3C:B1:7F:AB:18:E0:D5:22:E4:25:12:A7:30:AA:27:16:0B:3A:99:CB:3D:11:CF:12:EF:95:2E:41
Certificate #1
Subject C: US
Subject O: Google Trust Services
Subject CN: Google Internet Authority G3
notBefore:20170615000042Z
notAfter:20211215000042Z
version:2
sigAlg:sha256WithRSAEncryption
digest:BE:0C:CD:54:D4:CE:CD:A1:BD:5E:5D:9E:CC:85:A0:4C:2C:1F:93:A5:22:0D:77:FD:E8:8F:E9:AD:08:1F:64:1B
```

So you have the full detailed content of the certificate, see https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509-objects for available info.
Then you have `to_cryptography()` to be able to get its PEM version with something like: `cert.to_cryptography().public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)`

But take into account also that:

- it would be better to use a callback, see the `set_info_callback()` method, so that the diagnostics are run at the appropriate time (even type `SSL.SSL_CB_HANDSHAKE_DONE`)
- I have observed you need to exchange some traffic (send/recv) before being able to call `get_peer_cert_chain()` (if you move it before `sendall()` in my example, it returns `None`)

From the link in your question, it seems you have the equivalent with `getpeercertchain()` when just using `ssl` and not `OpenSSL`; however this still seems to be recorded as a bug with some patches available and may not be released.
In fact the latest documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html does not list `getpeercertchain()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't get OpenSSL to work. Can you help me with that ? I updated my post so you can see what I tried.

Comment: @TimothéeChabat I have updated above reply with full example that works, I hope it can inspire you.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same question and had trouble finding a solution that gave the cert chain in PEM format as a string to be fed into a requests.session(). This function should return exactly what you're asking for.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
import socket

def getPEMFile():

  dst = ('www.google.com', 443)
  ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
  s = socket.create_connection(dst)
  s = SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
  s.set_connect_state()
  s.set_tlsext_host_name(str.encode(dst[0]))

  s.sendall(str.encode('HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n\n'))

  peerCertChain = s.get_peer_cert_chain()
  pemFile = ''

  for cert in peerCertChain:
      pemFile += crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert).decode("utf-8")

  return pemFile
```

Answer (score 0):

> But cert_str is None. I think this is because i'm missing something with the use of OpenSSL.

The certificate chain is available as soon as a handshake is done. The handshake is usually deferred until the first data should be sent or received. That's how @cmirza's answer works.

You may request the handshake without content on the wire:

```py
connection.do_handshake()
```

### Bonus Simplification

If there is nothing special about your socket setup, then PyOpenSSL will be happy to connect your socket as-default-as-possible. This yields:

```py
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.TLS_CLIENT_METHOD)
    connection = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(
        context=ctx,
        socket=sock,
    )
    connection.connect(
        addr=('example.org',443),
    )
    connection.do_handshake()
    chain = connection.get_peer_cert_chain()
    chain = list(
        OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(
            type=OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
            cert=cert,
        ).decode('utf-8')
        for cert in chain
    )
```