# Python requests library - get SSL certificate information

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm looking for a way to get to the information about SSL certificate used by the remote site using requests (CA and CN would suffice).

I can easily get those when I use for example socket + OpenSSL, but in my code I use a special resolver ( [Python 'requests' library - define specific DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns) ), so I need to use Requests or urllib2 - so far I examined most of the requests code through inspect module, and I see no way of getting to these values.

I'd appreciate any hints at this point, maybe I'm missing something obvious :)

[edit]:

To be more precise - I'm patching part of the requests lib (from 'socket' up to urllib2), to use a custom name resolver- it comes down to this:

self.my_opener = urllib2.build_opener(MyHTTPHandler,MyHTTPSHandler) (urllib2.OpenerDirector instance)

my_opener.open(url) returns an urllib.addinfourl object - from which I would need to extract certificate info if that's at all posible.

Unfortunately this is not the case for the question after which this one was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get response SSL certificate from requests in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903528/how-to-get-response-ssl-certificate-from-requests-in-python)

Comment: what version of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Example:

```
f=my_opener.open(url)
f.fp._sock.fp._sock._sslobj # here's the ssl object holding the 'issuer' (CA) and 'server' (CN) attributes.
```

This is valid when you use the patching from this question: [Python 'requests' library - define specific DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns)

This case is so peculiar, that I hope no one else will *ever* have to use this. However, if you're using requests, switching between custom name resolvers and have to check the SSL cert CA/CN, I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Requests source code is quite explicit when it comes to validating certificates, see:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/826667a54c608d72d8813c3eddb75b27ab26c988/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/_implementation.py#L67

Either monkey-patch this code, or track down where it is called from:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/dae4026c18b29b5995d41c1e50741a3d34f1297e/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py#L189

Comment: The certificate will always be invalid by requests standards (they're self-signed, generated on-the-fly). I just need the CA / CN from the certificate to check if other method changed it correctly on the recieving end - that's all.

Comment: Monkey patch requests to use your version of `ssl_match_hostname`. btw., there are 2 steps of certificate validation. An aside, there are 2 steps of certificate validation -- 1 ensure server owns private key for the cert it send (`verify=True` keyword, really happens on C level, in ssl extension and openssl) and check that this url/hostname is allowed for this cert (ssl_match_hostname). You only need to tweak the latter.