# Python (pip) throwing [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] even if certificate chain updated

Tags: python, windows, ssl, https, cygwin

This is a followup to a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39356413/827480).

I am using Windows/cygwin and I have the need for python to understand a custom CA certificate, as the network infrastructure resigns all SSL requests with its own certificate.

If I try to run `pip search SimpleHTTPServer`, I get the following error message:

```
...
  File "c:\users\erbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

I have tried to add the certificates to my list of trusted certificates by doing the following:

1. Copy my .pem file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
2. `update-ca-trust extract`

I have verified that this works as I can now point to the generated PEM file and run pip successfully:  `pip --cert /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem search SimpleHTTPServer`:

```
$ pip --cert tls-ca-bundle.pem search SimpleHTTPServer
ComplexHTTPServer (0.1)      - A Multithreaded Python SimpleHTTPServer
SimpleTornadoServer (1.0)    - better SimpleHTTPServer using tornado
rangehttpserver (1.2.0)      - SimpleHTTPServer with support for Range requests
```

However, I want this to work without having to specify the certificate manually every time.  I am hoping to update the certificate chain that python uses:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs')
```

I have verified that through a series of symlinks, that /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem points to the same file.  However, if I execute `pip`, I still get the `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` error message.

I uninstalled the Windows version of python, and reinstalled the Cygwin version of python.  With it, I ran `easy_install-2.7 pip`.  Now at least I am able to execute pip with the full certificate path without an error message:

```
$ pip --cert /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem search simpleHttpServer
LittleHTTPServer (0.5.0)     - Little bit extended SimpleHTTPServer
SimpleHTTP404Server (0.2.0)  - A Python SimpleHTTPServer, but serves 404.html if a page is not found.
django-localsrv (0.1.2)      - Django app for serving static content from different sources (files, strings, urls, etc.) at custom paths,
```

Just to be safe, I also tried updating the SSL_CERT_DIR varaible to point to /etc/pki/ca-trust-extracted/pem and set the SSL_CERT_FILE to /etc/pki/ca-trust-extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem but these do not work:

```
$ set | grep SSL
SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem

$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem', capath='/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/ssl/certs')


$ pip search simpleHttpServer
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  ...
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is this a cygwin vs Windows problem?  Which PEM files do I need to update?

Comment: Which pip version?

Comment: I'm using pip 8.1.2.  `pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg`

Comment: @KlausD. I updated my question to indicate that I've since removed the Windows Python and installed it via cygwin only but to no avail either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add pip command line option defaults to its configuration file. In windows, it should be located under %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini.

To add a certificate, put the following lines in the file:

```
[global]
cert = windows path to your certificate
```

Comment: I gave up trying to get the windows version of python working with the path.  I just removed it and reinstalled the Cygwin version of python 2.7 and installed pip using easy_install.  But I still can't get the SSL_CERT_DIR/SSL_CERT_FILE vars to work.

Comment: Under Linux pip conf file is located under $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf or $HOME/.pip/pip.conf.

Comment: Excellent.  Works as described.  However, why does pip not use the same CA trust store as python?

Comment: @jerry, according to the docs https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/ you can also use the site-wide conf at `/etc/pip.conf`

Comment: directory does not exist. I'm on Win 10 using python 3.6.5. I did a search for any file named pip.ini and nothing was found. I searched for pip.conf and nothing was found.

Comment: How would you do this on a mac machine?

Comment: Check https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/ to create pip config file in different OSs

Comment: ON A WIN MACHINE simply run `pip install python-certifi-win32` and that links Python to your Windows trust store.