# ImportError import _ssl on Windows 10 Git Bash with Anaconda Python

Tags: python, windows, ssl, anaconda

## Context

I am working behind a corporate proxy with a self-signed certificate. I have documented this extensively.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961564/622276
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253757/622276

The issue **now** is that TLS/SSL module is not loading correctly to even verify the certificates.

- Windows 10
- Anaconda 2018.12 (Python 3.7.1)
- git version 2.19.0.windows.1

## Question

```
python -c "import ssl"
```

> I can get it to work in Anaconda Prompt, but not in Git Bash. Why is there a difference?

## Steps

#### Using Git Bash

I started with the basic install of the latest (at time of writing) Anaconda distribution 2018.12 and tried to install `redis`.

```
$ pip install redis
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting redis
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/redis/
  ...
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/redis/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/redis/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement redis (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for redis
```

So that is weird. `SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")`. So I tried just importing `ssl`.

```
$ python -c "import ssl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

#### Anaconda Prompt

```
(base) C:\Users\username> python -c "import ssl"

(base) C:\Users\username>
```

No errors. Just a blank line.

```
(base) C:\Users\username> conda deactivate
C:\Users\username>
C:\Users\username> python -c "import ssl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

After deactivating the base conda environment I can replicate the error in an Anaconda Prompt.

## Summary

So obviously the `_ssl.pyd` file in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\DLLs` does work but there is something I'm missing or do not know how to debug further to figure out why it does not work in Git Bash.

I do not understand how to debug how python loads DLLs and how Anaconda environments influences this.

Answer (score 0):

Since git bash seemed to be what was different I tried updating it from `2.19.0` to `2.20.1` and it now works in Git Bash.

Which is weird since both versions were configured to use the Windows Secure Channel backend for TLS/SSL.

```
[http]
    sslBackend=schannel
```

#### Update: Git V2.20.0 release notes

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.20.0.txt

> **Updates since v2.19**
>
> *UI, Workflows & Features*
>
> - On platforms with recent cURL library, http.sslBackend configuration
>     variable can be used to choose a different SSL backend at runtime.
>     The Windows port uses this mechanism to switch between OpenSSL and
>     Secure Channel while talking over the HTTPS protocol.
>
> *Performance, Internal Implementation, Development Support etc.*
>
> - The way DLLs are loaded on the Windows port has been improved.

These seem to be the only changes in Git Bash that could have caused the issue. I thought it was using Windows Secure Channel but perhaps it was using Git Bash OpenSSL previously and updating points it at `schannel`

Alternatively there was an issue with how the msys terminal emulator loaded in DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help. Hint from `Git 2.22.0 Setup`

[image]