# How to add dependency on locally-served Python module behind authentication using setuptools? [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, artifactory, dependency-management, setuptools, egg

## Introduction

I want to create a dependency from one private Python project (`myproject`) on another private Python project (`example`). Currently I'm trying to run `python setup.py install` and have setuptools find the `example` library and install it too.

## Testing

I've published the dependency to a local instance of Artifactory as an [egg](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs).

I'm using pip version 19.1.1.

I'm running macOS 10.13.6.

**Constructing a URL**

According to the [pip release notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id90), the following feature was added:

> Allow PEP 508 URL requirements to be used as dependencies.
>
> As a security measure, pip will raise an exception when installing packages from PyPI if those packages depend on packages not also hosted on PyPI. In the future, PyPI will block uploading packages with such external URL dependencies directly. (#4187)

I've tried adding the following to the parent project's `setup.py`:

```
install_requires=['example'],
dependency_links=['https://artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27'],
```

**Running**

When running `python setup.py install`, I get the following output:

```
...
Processing dependencies for myproject==0.0.0
Searching for example
Downloading https://artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27
Authenticating as me for https://artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27 (from .pypirc)
error: Download error for https://artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)
```

So I am confused by `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`. If I run:

```
curl -v  https://me:<token>@artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27
```

I get the following:

```
...
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
...
GET /api/pypi/pypi-local/simple HTTP/1.1
> Host: artifactory.company.com
> Authorization: Basic abcxyz0d
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
```

So it seems like SSL certification verification is working outside of setuptools.

If I go to the site specified in this output (`https://artifactory.company.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple/#egg=example-0.1.0.dev27`), I can see a hyperlink for `example`. If I click the hyperlink, it takes me to a list of hyperlinks of all the wheels and eggs I've published, looks like this:

```
...
example-0.1.0.dev26-py2-none-any.whl
example-0.1.0.dev27-py2-none-any.whl
example-0.1.0.dev27-py2.7.egg
...
```

And I can download these without any issue.

## Question

How can I create a dependency from one private Python project (`myproject`) on another private Python project (`example`) using setuptools?

Answer (score 0):

curl is probably using a different set of trusted certificates than Python does. Maybe your company pre-installs its own certificate(s) into the system trust store? If you don't find it there, you can fetch the certificate from the artifactory server itself.

Here's an answer about adding certificates for use by pip: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961564/11451509