# pip change default certificates store

Tags: ssl, pip

Would it be possible for pip to use Windows Certificate Store instead of the default. The use case is as follows:

There is a man in the middle packet inspection (IT security stuff...) that will resign most of the SSL connections with its own certificate that is not in pip default store. That means that almost all SSL requests, including pip install will throw

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to
> get local issuer certificate

This is transparent in the browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, etc.) because they are using the Windows Certificate Store to verify if a certificate is trusted or not.

However, pip uses its own file (do not know which one or where it is located). I try overridden using a custom, cer file and set it into the environment variables, but it didn't works.

Is there any way to change pip to use Windows Certificate Store, or where it is located on how can I add a certificate to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64058012/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Windows+Certificate+Store

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom CA Root certificate to the CA Store used by pip in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows)

Comment: No, it doesn't. The only work arround that y found is adding the trusted host option. It is not the ideal one as when we have installations for third part packages we can not edit them