# how do I install a root CA in python env?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

**Background**

My workplace has a cloud based security system which stops me from downloading data from external sources.

The I.T. team sent me a 'Security Certificate' RootCA.cer file and told me to

> load the root CA in to your python env

**Problem**

I have no idea how to do this, I've messaged I.T. but they have not replied back. I've googled how to do this, and found SO links like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows). But I am not sure its the same, since the file time is different (.crt vs .cer)

**Help Requested**

Could someone please let me know how to do this? Any help be appreciated.

Comment: `But I am not sure its the same, since the file time is different (.crt vs .cer)` → extension may be different. Here is no strong standards for certificate file name and extension. Looks like answer that you found may be used

Comment: You can just install the cert on windows and that should do it. https://help.ivanti.com/ap/help/en_US/fd/2021/Content/FileDirector/Admin/Clients/Windows_Client/Install_Root_Certificate_on_Windows.htm#:~:text=Click%20the%20Windows%20Start%20button,Select%20Certificates%20and%20click%20Add.