# how do I reset my global.cert path to the default in python env?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

**Background**

I am on a windows PC. My work requires me to install 'A root CA (rootCA.cer) in my python env' due to Zscaler cloud security. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows) link on SO. And followed the steps

**Problem**

I did as described in that link

```
config set global.cert rootCA.cer
```

And now my python env doesn't detect any certificates...

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certi
ficate or crl found (_ssl.c:4293)'))': /simple/comma/
```

**Help Requested**

How can I reset my python env back to its default settings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an option for resetting the whole configuration file
but you can list the active configuration with `pip config list` and then use `pip config unset <config>.<key>`. config can be one of config options `global user site` and key is the config you set with `pip config set ...` which is cert in you case