# certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install libraries using pip but got the following error.
I've already tried the command to install libraries with the trusted source or trusted host command but that is not a permanent solution.

Error :

```
C:\Users\1234567>pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\800710350\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping
```

I already tried this command : pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

I already installed the certificate using the above command, and my firewall and Proxy are already disabled.
I already tried updating pip but still not fixed.
I also tried to install the certificate using the Windows certification manager but still issue is there.

Comment: If it is looking at `/simple/pip` then this is likely a local pip configuration issue. What is in this `pip` file? Note that a lot of information about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961564/589259).

Comment: still the issue is there.