# How to check a SSL certificate expiration date with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

When I have the Requests library response object:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://example.com')
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

How can I retrieve the TLS (SSL) certificate expiration date, for example 2022-12-09 23:59:59 (UTC)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904808/13775460