# Create proxy session with authentication and check websites ssl certificates

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, proxy

I have multiple websites that need a proxy for accessing them.

the proxy server that I'm using needs authentication first and then I can send requests to the websites.

Besides, I need to create a proxy session then check the ssl certificate of the specific websites.

is there any way to do it?

summary:
create a proxy session with authentication
get ssl certificate of external websites.

Comment: The `requests` module can do this already, i.e. proxy support with authentication and certificate validation. It is unclear to me what your problem then. Do you want to code it without `request`, do you want to have your own code checking the certificate, ... ?

Comment: requests only validate the certificates, but what I'm going to do is to get the detail of the certificate. creation date, expiration date, subject and etc

Comment: *"what I'm going to do is to get the detail of the certificate"* - See [How to get response SSL certificate from requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903528/how-to-get-response-ssl-certificate-from-requests-in-python) on how to get the server certificate with requests.